# Dotted underline/bottom-border w/ Authorize.Net site seal

Tags: html, css, border

I'm very new to the programming/coding world so please excuse any/all obvious ignorance...

I have an .html page I routinely 'practice' fixes on located here:  **[LINK](http://www.weyhrauchlaw.com/sample_2.html)**

At the bottom of the page there is an Authorize.Net site seal w/ a dotted line/bottom border that I've been trying to remove for some time.  I've searched this site for any number of fixes

`(text-decoration:none; style="border:none;")`

among many others.  I suspect there is a style being applied that eludes these fixes.  My question is how to remove this bottom dotted line/border from this site seal/image?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated -- thanks for taking the time to read/suggest any fixes to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`border: none` on the `<a>` element around the Authorize.Net `<img>` should work. In the CSS, I would suggest putting:

```
div.AuthorizeNetSeal a {
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `a { border-bottom: 1px dotted #003F72; }` in you `site.css`. You should remove it (seems to be overridden one each `<a>`).

Otherwise, to remove just this border: `.AuthorizeNetSeal a { border: none; }`.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion before posting here -- didn't work.  The suggestion above removed the dotted line/border just fine...thanks for posting!